# Opening a serialport, transmitting on txd, dtr and rts

Tags: serial-port, tcl, tk-toolkit

Morning all,

I have developed an app with C# and Windows Forms that opens a serialport and transmits on txd, dtr and rts.

I want to be able to do this with tcl/tk but finding serialport tutorials on tcl/tk is proving quite difficult. I did find something on Stackoverflow [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022535/free-compiler-or-interpreter-for-tcl-and-tcl-serial-port-com1-commands). But when running it:

It says "couldn't open serial "COM7": permission denied"

Does anyone know why permission is denied and how to grant permission? Also does this code even work.

Does anyone have any sample code I can try or can point me to a good understandable source please?

Comment: Are you _sure_ that the device is present? And not in use by another program?

Comment: Yeah it shows as prolific USB to Serial Comm Port (COM7) in device manager. I have used it in MS visual studio but that closed. Has anyone not had experience with tcl/tk that has any ideas on how to get it working?

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at this example that uses a Tcl/tk to read data from a serial port:

```
############################################
# A first quick test if you have a modem

# open com2: for reading and writing
# For UNIX'es use the appropriate devices /dev/xxx
set serial [open com2: r+]

# setup the baud rate, check it for your configuration
fconfigure $serial -mode "9600,n,8,1"

# don't block on read, don't buffer output
fconfigure $serial -blocking 0 -buffering none

# Send some AT-command to your modem
puts -nonewline $serial "AT\r"

# Give your modem some time, then read the answer
after 100
puts "Modem echo: [read $serial]"

############################################
# Example (1): Poll the comport periodically
set serial [open com2: r+]
fconfigure $serial -mode "9600,n,8,1"
fconfigure $serial -blocking 0 -buffering none

while {1} {
    set data [read $serial]             ;# read ALL incoming bytes
    set size [string length $data]      ;# number of received byte, may be 0
    if { $size } {
        puts "received $size bytes: $data"
    } else {
        puts "<no data>"
    update      ;# Display output, allow to close wish-window
}

############################################
# Example (2): Fileevents
set serial [open com2: r+]
fconfigure $serial -mode "9600,n,8,1" -blocking 0 -buffering none -translation binary
fileevent $serial readable [list serial_receiver $serial]

proc serial_receiver { chan } {
    if { [eof $chan] } {
        puts stderr "Closing $chan"
        catch {close $chan}
        return
    }
    set data [read $chan]
    set size [string length $data]
    puts "received $size bytes: $data"
}
```

(disclaimer: this is taken verbatim from [here](https://wiki.tcl.tk/1108))

EDIT: I am sorry but I do not have enough reputation to comment, but it is probably a good idea to specify the platform to narrow down what the permission issues might be related to.

Comment: I am working with Windows 10 with a rs232 to usb cable connected to COM7. I tried the above example 1 but I get "couldn't open "com7:": no such file or directory" Is this a confirmed working example? Does serial not need to be initialised? Also forgot to mention I am using wish to run the code.

Comment: I think the example above works on an older Windows version. I would perhaps try to run `wish` with elevated permissions just to be sure. Another option might be to switch to Python, which is probably better supported these days.

Comment: I do have this working in C# but I need to do this with tcl/tk. Do you know how to run wish with elevated permissions by any chance?

Comment: For the elevated permissions, you could run `wish` + your script from a terminal that was opened with "Run as administrator".